# Algorithm to separate items of the same type

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a list of elements, each one identified with a type, I need to reorder the list to **maximize** the **minimum distance** between elements of the same type.

The set is small (10 to 30 items), so performance is not really important.

There's no limit about the quantity of items per type or quantity of types, the data can be considered random.

For example, if I have a list of:

- 5 items of A
- 3 items of B
- 2 items of C
- 2 items of D
- 1 item of E
- 1 item of F

I would like to produce something like:
`A`, `B`, `C`, `A`, `D`, `F`, `B`, `A`, `E`, `C`, `A`, `D`, `B`, `A`

- A has at least 2 items between occurences
- B has at least 4 items between occurences
- C has 6 items between occurences
- D has 6 items between occurences

Is there an algorithm to achieve this?

**-Update-**

After exchanging some comments, I came to a definition of a secondary goal:

- **main goal**: maximize the minimum distance between elements of the same type, considering only the type(s) with less distance.
- **secondary goal**: maximize the minimum distance between elements on *every* type. IE: if a combination increases the minimum distance of a certain type without decreasing other, then choose it.

**-Update 2-**

About the answers.
There were a lot of useful answers, although none is a solution for both goals, specially the second one which is tricky.

Some thoughts about the answers:

- *PengOne*: Sounds good, although it doesn't provide a concrete implementation, and not always leads to the best result according to the second goal.
- *Evgeny Kluev*: Provides a concrete implementation to the main goal, but it doesn't lead to the best result according to the secondary goal.
- tobias_k: I liked the random approach, it doesn't always lead to the best result, but it's a good approximation and cost effective.

I tried a combination of Evgeny Kluev, backtracking, and tobias_k formula, but it needed too much time to get the result.

Finally, at least for my problem, I considered tobias_k to be the most adequate algorithm, for its simplicity and good results in a timely fashion. Probably, it could be improved using *Simulated annealing*.

Comment: What exactly do you want to maximize - mean distance, minimal distance, or something different?

Comment: Do you have to find the optimal solution? If not, you might try a randomized algorithm. Swap random elements, until the quality (e.g. mean distance between elements of same class) is good enough or does not increase any further.

Comment: I would like that the minium distance between 2 items of the same type is the maximum possible. In my example C and D have a distance of 6, but if increasing that distance means decreasing the distance between A items it's no good.

Comment: I don't think the randomized algorithm is good enough. A suboptimal soultion I could settle is that every item of the same type has as least the distance that can be achieved on the most repeated type. In my example A is the most repeated item and the best distance for A is 2, so every type should have at least two items between 2.

Comment: Lets say you have 3 A's and 2 B's. To possible solutions are: BAAAB and ABABA. In first solution the maximum for B (4) is realized, but not for A (only 1). In the second solution the maximum for B (2) is realized, but not for A (only 2). There is no solution where both maxima are realized. So, which of the two given solutions is the best in your opinion, and why?

Comment: ABABA because `minimum distance between 2 items of the same type is the maximum possible`. Perhaps there's a better way to formulate this statement, but I don't see it.

Comment: In other words, you want to maximize the minimum distance between items of the same type.

Comment: Maybe start with the most numerous, so that these have the best chances to be spread, whereas the least numerous need it the least. Update the indexes of the first and last free cells as they become used. Try to spread evenly.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounded like an interesting problem, so I just gave it a try. Here's my super-simplistic randomized approach, done in Python:

```
def optimize(items, quality_function, stop=1000):
    no_improvement = 0
    best = 0
    while no_improvement < stop:
        i = random.randint(0, len(items)-1)
        j = random.randint(0, len(items)-1)
        copy = items[::]
        copy[i], copy[j] = copy[j], copy[i]
        q = quality_function(copy)
        if q > best:
            items, best = copy, q
            no_improvement = 0
        else:
            no_improvement += 1
    return items
```

As already discussed in the comments, the really tricky part is the quality function, passed as a parameter to the optimizer. After some trying I came up with one that almost always yields optimal results. Thank to *pmoleri*, for pointing out how to make this a whole lot more efficient.

```
def quality_maxmindist(items):
    s = 0
    for item in set(items):
        indcs = [i for i in range(len(items)) if items[i] == item]
        if len(indcs) > 1:
            s += sum(1./(indcs[i+1] - indcs[i]) for i in range(len(indcs)-1))
    return 1./s
```

And here some random result:

```
>>> print optimize(items, quality_maxmindist)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'F', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'A']
```

Note that, passing another quality function, the same optimizer could be used for different list-rearrangement tasks, e.g. as a (rather silly) randomized sorter.

Comment: Hi tobias_k, I liked the super-simplicity of your approach, and I found the quality function useful. I'm combining 'Evgeny Kluev' strategy for the larger sets as it seems to lead to an optimal result, backtracking for the smaller ones and your quality function to select a result. I'll put here the result when it's polished. In the meantime, I changed the quality function to consider only consecutive indexes instead of all the combinations, what do you think? `[1./abs(indcs[i],indcs[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(indcs) - 1)]`

Comment: @pmoleri Sounds like a neat idea, combining the approaches in this way. Concerning the quality-function: You are right, comparing only consecutive indices should indeed be enough, and on larger data sets, this could actually make quite a difference. I'll update my post accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

First, you don't have a well-defined optimization problem yet. If you want to maximized the minimum distance between two items of the same type, that's well defined. If you want to maximize the minimum distance between two A's and between two B's and ... and between two Z's, then that's not well defined. How would you compare two solutions:

1. A's are at least 4 apart, B's at least 4 apart, and C's at least 2 apart
2. A's at least 3 apart, B's at least 3 apart, and C's at least 4 apart

You need a well-defined measure of "good" (or, more accurately, "better"). I'll assume for now that the measure is: ***maximize the minimum distance between any two of the same item***.

Here's an algorithm that achieves a minimum distance of `ceiling(N/n(A))` where `N` is the total number of items and `n(A)` is the number of items of instance `A`, assuming that `A` is the most numerous.

- Order the item types `A1, A2, ... , Ak` where `n(Ai) >= n(A{i+1})`.
- Initialize the list `L` to be empty.
- For `j` from `k` to `1`, distribute items of type `Ak` as uniformly as possible in `L`.

Example: Given the distribution in the question, the algorithm produces:

```
F
E, F
D, E, D, F
D, C, E, D, C, F
B, D, C, E, B, D, C, F, B
A, B, D, A, C, E, A, B, D, A, C, F, A, B
```

Comment: The constraint is well-defined. Read the very last comment from the OP.

Comment: `maximized the minimum distance between two items of the same type` is what I want (as I put in the previous comments) unless someone come up with a better/less ambiguous definition. What happends if you can't keep two `C` from appearing between two `D`?

Comment: I think it works nice when I have at least one type of every quantity of items, ie: A*3, B*2, C*1. But if one is missing, ie: A*4, B*2, C*1. How do I decide which is the most uniform distribution? `A,B,A,B,A,A` or `A,B,A,A,B,A` or `A,A,B,A,B,A`.

Comment: @pmoleri It doesn't matter which choice you make. They all have the same ***maximum minimum distance***, so they are equally "good".

Comment: I agree, it doesn't matter in that stage, but when you continue adding elements, example: C*1, D*1. Which is the most uniform position? Of course, I would like to separate the two A, but that's not de definition for uniform.

Comment: @pmoleri They are **equally** uniform. Choose whichever convention you like. If the list has `k` items, then there are `k+1` positions. Any **as uniform as possible** distribution of items of type `X` will have the distance between consecutive `X`s be `i` or `i+1`. There won't usually be a **unique** solution.

Comment: Using this algorithm I could arrive to results like this one: AABABA -> AABCABA -> AABCDABA. It's not a *unique* solution nor a correct one, as I have to A together.

Comment: @pmoleri No. That's why the algorithm starts with the ***least numerous** item type. In that example, start by placing `D`, then `C`, then two `B`'s then three `A`s.

Comment: Sorry, I kept thinking the algorithm the other way around. Now, in your example, if the algorithm stops in the third step, I would prefer the result `D,E,F,D` instead of `D,E,D,F`. Perhaps the last step should behave different?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16570/discussion-between-pengone-and-pmoleri)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an algorithm that only maximizes the minimum distance between elements of the same type and does nothing beyond that. The following list is used as an example:

```
AAAAA BBBBB CCCC DDDD EEEE FFF GG
```

- Sort element sets by number of elements of each type in descending order. Actually only largest sets (A & B) should be placed to the head of the list as well as those element sets that have one element less (C & D & E). Other sets may be unsorted.
- Reserve R last positions in the array for one element from each of the largest sets, divide the remaining array evenly between the S-1 remaining elements of the largest sets. This gives optimal distance: K = (N - R) / (S - 1). Represent target array as a 2D matrix with K columns and L = N / K full rows (and possibly one partial row with N % K elements). For example sets we have R = 2, S = 5, N = 27, K = 6, L = 4.
- If matrix has S - 1 full rows, fill first R columns of this matrix with elements of the largest sets (A & B), otherwise sequentially fill all columns, starting from last one.

For our example this gives:

```
AB....
AB....
AB....
AB....
AB.
```

If we try to fill the remaining columns with other sets in the same order, there is a problem:

```
ABCDE.
ABCDE.
ABCDE.
ABCE..
ABD
```

The last 'E' is only 5 positions apart from the first 'E'.

- Sequentially fill all columns, starting from last one.

For our example this gives:

```
ABFEDC
ABFEDC
ABFEDC
ABGEDC
ABG
```

Returning to linear array we have:

```
ABFEDCABFEDCABFEDCABGEDCABG
```

---

Here is an attempt to use simulated annealing for this problem (C sources): http://ideone.com/OGkkc.

Comment: AAAAA + BB + CC +E -> ABABACACAE when optimal should be: ABACEABACA, as distance between Bs and Cs is bigger. But perhaps that's what you mean with `nothing beyond that`, as both solutions have *at least* one item between items of the same type.

Comment: Both ABABACACAE and ABACEABACA are equally optimal if we only maximize minimal distance. Which allows this very simple algorithm. To make ABACEABACA optimal, you need some formal definition of optimality, different from "maximize minimal distance". Which, most likely, will make the problem more complicated.

Comment: I agree. Although "maximize minimal distance" can have two readings, a global one, that is what you did, but can also be applied to every type individually, making ABACEABACA optimal for types B and C, without breaking the global goal. Perhaps can be considered a main goal and a secondary goal.
I like your algorithm to accomplish the main goal, I think it's similar to PengOne's but working from larger to smaller and with a concrete implementation.

Comment: This main/secondary definition is still unclear. Do you want maximize minimal distance for most frequent elements, then maximize average minimal distance for other sets? Or possibly maximize minimal distance for most frequent elements, fix this distance, then maximize minimal distance for less frequent elements, fix it again, then do it for even less frequent elements, etc.?

Comment: Probably the second one. Or at least, if I can get a higher minimal distance in one type, without decreasing other types with minimal distance, then do it.

Probably, using your algorithm for the larger sets an then a backtracking for the smaller ones, can be achieved. What do you think?

Comment: Then it's worth to specify it in the question. Not many people read so deep in the comments... Yes, I think, this algorithm may be used to distribute larger sets, then continue with either backtracking or simulated annealing.

Comment: @pmoleri: On second thought, distributing larger sets with this algorithm prevents optimization for "secondary goal". Counterexample set sizes: 9,8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1. Optimal distances 2, 3. But tightly packing larger set allows only 2, 2. So the only usable part of this algorithm for the updated problem is calculation of optimal distance for the largest sets

Comment: Yes, I think so too. But I think is the best algorithm to achieve the main goal. I used your algorithm for the largest and largest-1 sets with the exception of only using the last row for the largests sets. Then continue with backtracking iterating over possible types at each step and using @tobias_k quality function to select the best result. I'm still polishing it, I will put it here afterwards.

Comment: Now you can compare it with my results. (See link in updated answer). I didn't use any static allocation for largest sets, used different quality function, and used simulated annealing instead of simple randomized approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, a "brute force on the output" one, that doesn't guarantee an exact results (<1% error by my emphiric tests), but it's quite faster than the ones provided here. It works on any kind of serializable element, mixed lists too, not just on integers.

It works starting from the "most repeated element", writing to the out array, and goes down. If a space is occupied in the out array, it find an available one, jumping back and forth (that's the part that's not guarantee precision)

If somebody needs speed instead of precision, this can be a good option, it gives an acceptable result

```
from collections import defaultdict

def find_nearest_none(arr, position):
    """
    Find the nearest None value to the given position in the array.
    """
    if arr[position] is None:
        return position

    step = 1
    while True:
        left_pos = position - step
        right_pos = position + step

        if right_pos < len(arr) and arr[right_pos] is None:
            return right_pos
        elif left_pos >= 0 and arr[left_pos] is None:
            return left_pos
        elif left_pos < 0 and right_pos >= len(arr):
            # Both left and right positions are out of bounds
            return False

        step += 1

def max_distance_list(nums):
    """
    Rearrange the elements in the list to maximize the smallest distance
    between any two occurrences of the same number.
    """
    num_occurrences = {}
    total_elements = len(nums)
    output_list = [None] * total_elements

    # Count the occurrences of each number in the list
    for num in nums:
        num_occurrences[num] = num_occurrences.get(num, 0) + 1

    # Sort the numbers by their occurrences in descending order
    sorted_occurrences = sorted(num_occurrences.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)

    # Group the numbers by their occurrences
    grouped_data = defaultdict(list)
    for number, occurrence_count in sorted_occurrences:
        grouped_data[occurrence_count].append(number)

    start_pos = 0   # start position
    iterations = 0

    # Iterate over the grouped data, starting from the items that occur most
    for occurrences, numbers in dict(grouped_data).items():
        # Iterate over each number with the same occurrences
        for number in numbers:
            # Calculate the optimal separation between occurrences
            optimal_separation = (total_elements + 1) / occurrences
            position = start_pos
            iterations += 1

            # Iterate over every occurrence of the current number
            for i in range(occurrences):
                # Write the last occurrence nearest the end as possible
                if i == occurrences - 1:
                    position = total_elements - iterations

                # Find the nearest free position to the optimal one
                free_pos = find_nearest_none(output_list, int(round(position, 0)))

                # Place the number in the output list
                output_list[free_pos] = number

                # Increment position by the optimal (float) separation
                position += optimal_separation

            start_pos += 1

    return output_list
```

some tests:

```
[tobias_k] elements: 200  -- Tot time: 12.138919353485107
[my_func] elements: 200  -- Tot time: 0.0003261566162109375
[tobias_k] elements: 400  -- Tot time: 81.43994617462158
[my_func] elements: 400  -- Tot time: 0.0006806850433349609
[tobias_k] elements: 600  -- Tot time: 153.45782017707825
[my_func] elements: 600  -- Tot time: 0.0010495185852050781


AABCBAD --> ['A', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A']
AAA --> ['A', 'A', 'A']
AAB --> ['A', 'B', 'A']
AABBC --> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A']
AABBBCC --> ['B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B'] # ie this is not optimal
AAAAABBBCCDDEF --> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'F', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
['t1', 't2', 't2', 't2', 't2', 't3', 't4', 22, 22, 22, 22] --> ['t2', 22, 't4', 't2', 22, 't3', 't2', 22, 't1', 22, 't2']
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could see your problem like a bunch of particles that physically repel eachother.  You could iterate to a 'stable' situation.

Basic pseudo-code:

```
force( x, y ) = 0 if x.type==y.type
                1/distance(x,y) otherwise 

nextposition( x, force ) = coined?(x) => same
                           else => x + force

notconverged(row,newrow) = // simplistically
   row!=newrow

row=[a,b,a,b,b,b,a,e]; 
newrow=nextposition(row);
while( notconverged(row,newrow) )
   newrow=nextposition(row);
```

I don't know if it converges, but it's an idea :)

Comment: I like the physics approach. But I guess it can converge to a suboptimal result depending on the initial position, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there may be a more efficient solution, but here is one possibility for you:

First, note that it is very easy to find an ordering which produces a minimum-distance-between-items-of-same-type of 1. Just use any random ordering, and the MDBIOST will be at least 1, if not more.

So, start off with the assumption that the MDBIOST will be 2. Do a recursive search of the space of possible orderings, *based on the assumption that MDBIOST will be 2*. There are a number of conditions you can use to prune branches from this search. Terminate the search if you find an ordering which works.

If you found one that works, try again, under the assumption that MDBIOST will be 3. Then 4... and so on, until the search fails.

**UPDATE:** It would actually be better to start with a *high* number, because that will constrain the possible choices more. Then gradually reduce the number, until you find an ordering which works.

Comment: I guess is more efficient than trying all the combinations, as the assumption lets you cut branches.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach.

If every item must be kept at least k places from every other item of the same type, then write down items from left to right, keeping track of the number of items left of each type. At each point put down an item with the largest number left that you can legally put down.

This will work for N items if there are no more than ceil(N / k) items of the same type, as it will preserve this property - after putting down k items we have k less items and we have put down at least one of each type that started with at ceil(N / k) items of that type.

Given a clutch of mixed items you could work out the largest k you can support and then lay out the items to solve for this k.