# How to rearrange items of different kind so that the distance between the same kind is maximum?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm to separate items of the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375831/algorithm-to-separate-items-of-the-same-type)

There is an interesting problem from my friend's project. He works in TV ad placement. The ads are of different kinds: mobile, foods, banks etc. He needs to rearrange the list of ads so that the ads of a similar kind are placed at the maximum distance one from another. There are around 100 ads in an ad block, so the brute force solution is not feasible.
Is it possible to come up with a reasonably fast solution (<30 secs)? What is the fastest possible way to do this?

Assume each ad is of same length.

Example: 

`[M, M, F, B, F, B]`. In this particular scenario the output could be: `[M, F, B, M, F, B]`

Comment: Can you better describe the problem? How much dimension is each ad? How is the distance defined? Can you give a simple test case of input+output?

Comment: did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375831/algorithm-to-separate-items-of-the-same-type

Comment: We need some kind of formula, to estimate 'how bad'/'how good' a permutation of ads is, do you have one specific to your problem?

Comment: Not sure about the "dimension" of an ad. The input is just a list of ads of different type, we can assume that each ad is of the same length. For instance: [M, M, F, B, F, B]. In this particular scenario the output could be: [M, F, B, M, F, B].

Comment: I guess a good optimization function would be minimum distance between ads of the same type. This distance should be maximum possible.

Comment: I agree; we need an actual heuristic to judge potential answers. Do we want to maximize the minimum distance? Or maximize the average?

Comment: Brute force is reasonably fast, O(N^2) is only 10,000 for 100, and 30 seconds are _an eternity_ for a computer. That said, relaxation is probably a lot more elegant. Also, the "trivial" solution of equidistributing items of one category and some form of "slight local mixing" might be just good enough. It will not give a perfect solution, but perfect is normally not really needed.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to maximize the minimum distance. First, count how many of each type of item you have (the sum of all of these should be the number of items, `n`, in the list). Sort the list of unique kinds of items according to their frequencies. Then, prepare an output tape with `n` cells. Starting with the most frequent element, evenly place the elements in the output tape at regular intervals. Continue in decreasing order of item frequency, considering only empty cells on the tape. This is `O(n + m log m)`, where `n` is the total number of items and `m` is the number of unique items (i.e., kinds of items). Note that, in this case, you can probably get away with using a linear sorting algorithm on the kinds of items, so you could lose the `log m` factor, although in practice (for 100 items, and presumably many fewer kinds of items) I don't know whether it would be worth it.

On your example: [M, M, F, B, F, B]. We have (M, 2), (F, 2), (B, 2). We get [M, _, _, M, _, _] after the first pass, [M, F, _, M, F, _] after the second and [M, F, B, M, F, B] after the third.

Note that this is a heuristic, and I suspect that it may be optimal, but I have not attempted to demonstrate that this is optimal, not even to myself. However, if you have `n` elements and the most frequent element appears `x` times, the most the minimum distance could possibly be is `floor(n/x)` (EDIT: this isn't actually true, see my comment)... and that's what this heuristic is shooting for. There's a question, I suppose, of how to space items "evenly" if the numbers aren't even divisors... but even for examples I try where this occurs, just about any choice is OK w.r.t. the criterion we're optimizing against. A slightly harder example:

[A, A, A, A, A, B, B, B, C, C, D] gives us (A, 5), (B, 3), (C, 2), (D, 1); we get [A, _, A, _, A, _, A, _, A, _, _] after the first pass, [A, B, A, _, A, B, A, _, A, B, _] after the second pass, [A, B, A, C, A, B, A, C, A, B, _] after the third pass and we end up with [A, B, A, C, A, B, A, C, A, B, D]. Good enough for government work.

I can't think of an easy way to do better than this for minimizing the average distance, in fact. This should be plenty fast... is it close enough for your friend's needs?

Comment: One comment: it looks like this heuristic isn't really perfect. Consider the inputs [A, A, A, B, B, B, C] and [A, A, A, B, C, D, E]. In the first case, you should get [A, B, A, B, A, B, C], but in the second case you should get [A, B, C, A, D, E, A]. So my answer is not correct, in a strict sense. In practice, you probably want to play it safe when using this heuristic: err on the side of not spreading items out too much (I guess really shoot for `floor(n/x)`, don't try to do better... although sometimes you can!).