# Combining two lists with minimum distance between elements

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have to lists like these:

```
a = ["1a","2a","3a","4a","5a","6a","7a","8a","9a","10a","11a","12a","13a","14a"] 
b = ["1b","2b","3b","4b","5b","6b","7b","8b","9b","10b","11b","12b","13b","14b"]
```

**And what I want is to combine them, so that there is at least a difference of *n* elements between an element from *a* and it's corresponding element in *b*.**

As an example, if my *n* is 10, and "3a" is in position 3 and "3b" is in position 5, that isn't a solution since there's only a distance of 2 between these corresponding elements.

I have already solved this for the purpose I want through a brute force method: shuffle the union of the two arrays and see if the constraint is met; if not, shuffle again and so on... Needless to say, that for 14 elements array, sometimes there is 5 to 10 second computation to yield a solution with a minimum distance of 10. Even though that's kind of ok for what I am looking for, I am curious about how I could solve this in a more optimized way.

I am currently using Python, but code in any language (or pseudo-code) is more than welcomed.

**EDIT**: The context of this problem is something like a questionnarie, in which around 100 participants are expected to join in. Therefore, I am not necessarily interested in *all* the solutions, but rather something like the first 100.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there another condition which is not satisified by appending b to a?

Comment: If the constraint is not _totally_ hard, you could try an optimization approach as in [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12375831/1639625).

Comment: I assume this is some sort of survey with multiple questions essentially asking the same thing, to check whether the answers are consistent, so there should be a bit of randomness, I guess?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: appending a to b in indeed a solution, but I am looking for 100 solutions for instance. I have editted the question accordingly

Comment: @tobias_k: yes that's it totally the case yes.

Comment: Is the goal to have the test appear randomized? What is the benefit of the minimum distance (i.e. how does the minimum distance help)? Ignoring the context of the questionnaire, you could just take Andrew Morton's solution, but permute both `a` and `b` (with the same permutation!) and then append. Assuming that `|a| > 4` you'll generate more than 100 (since `5! > 100` and factorial is a monotonically increasing function).

Answer (score 1):

For your specific scenario, you could use a randomized approach -- though not as random as what you've already tried. Something like this:

1. start with a *random permutation* of the items in both lists
2. create a new permutation by creating a *copy* of the other and *randomly swapping* two items
3. measure the *quality* of the permutations, e.g., the sum of the distances of each pair of related items, or the minimum of such distances
4. if the quality of the new permutation is better than that of the original permutation, *keep the new one*, otherwise *discard the new one* and continue with the original permutation
5. *repeat from 2.* until each distance is at least *10* or until quality does not improve over a number of iterations

The difference to shuffling the *whole* list in each iteration (as in your approach) is that in each iteration the permutation *can only get better*, until a satisfying solution is found.

Each time you run this algorithm, the result will be slightly different, so you can run it 100 times for 100 different solutions. Of course, this algorithm *does not guarantee* to find a solution (much less all such solutions), but it should be fast enough so that you could just restart it in case it fails.

In Python, this could look somewhat like this (slightly simplified, but still working):

```py
def shuffle(A, B):
    # original positions, i.e. types of questions
    kind = dict([(item, i) for i, item in list(enumerate(A)) + list(enumerate(B))])

    # get positions of elements of kinds, and return sum of their distances
    def quality(perm):
        pos = dict([(kind[item], i) for i, item in enumerate(perm)])
        return sum(abs(pos[kind[item]] - i) for i, item in enumerate(perm))

    # initial permutation and quality
    current = A + B
    random.shuffle(current)
    best = quality(current)

    # improve upon initial permutation by randomly swapping items
    for g in range(1000):
        i = random.randint(0, len(current)-1)
        j = random.randint(0, len(current)-1)
        copy = current[:]
        copy[i], copy[j] = copy[j], copy[i]
        q = quality(copy)
        if q > best:
            current, best = copy, q

    return current
```

Example output for `print shuffle(a, b)`:

> ['14b', '2a', '13b', '3a', '9b', '4a', '6a', '1a', '8a', '5b', '12b', '11a', '10b', '7b', '4b', '11b', '5a', '7a', '8b', '12a', '13a', '14a', '1b', '2b', '3b', '6b', '10a', '9a']

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question, it is possible to perform all the ordering by relying exclusively on the indices of the arrays (i.e., on pure integers) and thus the problem can be reduced to create (valid) ranges instead of analysing each element.

for each a <= total_items-n , valid b = if(a + n == total_items){total_items} else{[a + n, total_items]}

For example:

n = 10;
total_items = 15;

for a = 1 -> valid b = [11, 15]

for a = 2 -> valid b = [12, 15]

, etc.

This would be perfomed 4 times: forwards and backwards for a respect to b and the same for b respect to a.

In this way you would reduce the number of iterations to its minimum expression and would get, as an output, a set of "solutions" for each position, rather than a one-to-one binding (that is what you have right now, isn't it?).

Answer (score 0):

If there are equivalents in Python to .NET's Lists and LINQ, then you may be able to directly convert the following code. It generates up to 100 lists really quickly: I press "debug" to run it and up pops a windows with the results in much less than a second.

```
' VS2012
Option Infer On

Module Module1

    Dim minDistance As Integer = 10
    Dim rand As New Random ' a random number generator

    Function OkToAppend(current As List(Of Integer), x As Integer) As Boolean
        ' see if the previous minDistance values contain the number x
        Return Not (current.Skip(current.Count - minDistance).Take(minDistance).Contains(x))
    End Function

    Function GenerateList() As List(Of String)
        ' We don't need to start with strings: integers will make it faster.
        ' The "a" and "b" suffixes can be sprinkled on at random once the
        ' list is created.
        Dim numbersToUse() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}

        Dim pool As New List(Of Integer)
        ' we need all the numbers twice
        pool.AddRange(numbersToUse)
        pool.AddRange(numbersToUse)

        Dim newList As New List(Of Integer)

        Dim pos As Integer

        For i = 0 To pool.Count - 1
            ' limit the effort it puts in
            Dim sanity As Integer = pool.Count * 10

            Do
                pos = rand.Next(0, pool.Count)
                sanity -= 1
            Loop Until OkToAppend(newList, pool(pos)) OrElse sanity = 0

            If sanity > 0 Then ' it worked
                ' append the value to the list
                newList.Add(pool(pos))
                ' remove the value which has been used
                pool.RemoveAt(pos)
            Else ' give up on this arrangement
                Return Nothing
            End If

        Next

        ' Create the final list with "a" and "b" stuck on each value.
        Dim stringList As New List(Of String)
        Dim usedA(numbersToUse.Length) As Boolean
        Dim usedB(numbersToUse.Length) As Boolean

        For i = 0 To newList.Count - 1
            Dim z = newList(i)
            Dim suffix As String = ""

            If usedA(z) Then
                suffix = "b"
            ElseIf usedB(z) Then
                suffix = "a"
            End If

            ' rand.Next(2) generates an integer in the range [0,2)
            If suffix.Length = 0 Then suffix = If(rand.Next(2) = 1, "a", "b")

            If suffix = "a" Then
                usedA(z) = True
            Else
                usedB(z) = True
            End If

            stringList.Add(z.ToString & suffix)
        Next

        Return stringList

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim arrangements As New List(Of List(Of String))
        For i = 1 To 100
            Dim thisArrangement = GenerateList()
            If thisArrangement IsNot Nothing Then
                arrangements.Add(thisArrangement)
            End If
        Next

        'TODO: remove duplicate entries and generate more to make it up to
        ' the required quantity.
        For Each a In arrangements
            ' outputs the elements of a with ", " as a separator
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", a))
        Next

        ' wait for user to press enter
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```