# python sort with adjacent difference

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of item

```
item = [a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,c,e,e,e,e,e,e]
```

I would like to sort it with mix up order, so adjacent allowed maximum duplicate twice, like

```
[a,a,b,a,b,b,c,c,b,b,c,e,c,c,e,e,e,e,e]
```

because there are no more item could be shuffle with e, so e will remain duplicate with adjacent.

is there any quick way to sort this?

### EDIT

To make it clear, give it a real life example, in a laptop category, I have 100 products from IBM, 10 products from Acer, 6 products from Apple, I want to sort the same brands to be as mix up as possible.

for example, 
unsorted list I have

```
[{brand:"ibm", "id":1},{brand:"ibm", "id":2},{brand:"ibm", "id":3},{brand:"ibm", "id":4},{brand:"ibm", "id":5},{brand:"ibm", "id":6},{brand:"acer", "id":7},{brand:"acer", "id":8},{brand:"acer", "id":9},{brand:"acer", "id":10},{brand:"apple", "id":11},{brand:"apple", "id":12}]
```

target result, as long as same brand are not adjacent each other, like first 10 all from same brand, but it is ok 2-3 same brand adjacent,

```
[{brand:"ibm", "id":1},,{brand:"acer", "id":7},{brand:"ibm", "id":2},{brand:"ibm", "id":3},{brand:"acer", "id":8},{brand:"apple", "id":12}{brand:"ibm", "id":4},{brand:"acer", "id":9},{brand:"ibm", "id":5},{brand:"ibm", "id":6},{brand:"acer", "id":10}]
```

it will be good not use random, but with a deterministic sort, so every time the user still see the same order, however it is not a must, since it could be saved into cache.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a random shuffle or a deterministic one?

Comment: You may want to have a look at this related question: [algorithm to separate items of the same type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375831/algorithm-to-separate-items-of-the-same-type)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## SECOND EDIT

Ok, well now I get it. You made this sound like a shuffle when it's really not like that. Here's an answer, a little more involved.

First I want to introduce `pprint`. This is just a version of `print` that formats things nicely:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(items)
#>>> [{'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 1},
#>>>  {'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 2},
#>>>  {'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 3},
#>>>  {'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 4},
#>>>  {'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 5},
#>>>  {'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 6},
#>>>  {'brand': 'acer', 'id': 7},
#>>>  {'brand': 'acer', 'id': 8},
#>>>  {'brand': 'acer', 'id': 9},
#>>>  {'brand': 'acer', 'id': 10},
#>>>  {'brand': 'apple', 'id': 11},
#>>>  {'brand': 'apple', 'id': 12}]
```

With that out of the way, here we go.

We want to group the items by brand:

```
from collections import defaultdict

brand2items = defaultdict(list)

for item in items:
    brand2items[item["brand"]].append(item)

pprint(brand2items)
#>>> {'acer': [{'brand': 'acer', 'id': 7},
#>>>           {'brand': 'acer', 'id': 8},
#>>>           {'brand': 'acer', 'id': 9},
#>>>           {'brand': 'acer', 'id': 10}],
#>>>  'apple': [{'brand': 'apple', 'id': 11}, {'brand': 'apple', 'id': 12}],
#>>>  'ibm': [{'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 1},
#>>>          {'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 2},
#>>>          {'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 3},
#>>>          {'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 4},
#>>>          {'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 5},
#>>>          {'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 6}]}
```

We can then get the values, 'cause we don't care about the key:

```
items_by_brand = list(brand2items.values())

pprint(items_by_brand)
#>>> [[{'brand': 'apple', 'id': 11}, {'brand': 'apple', 'id': 12}],
#>>>  [{'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 1},
#>>>   {'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 2},
#>>>   {'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 3},
#>>>   {'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 4},
#>>>   {'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 5},
#>>>   {'brand': 'ibm', 'id': 6}],
#>>>  [{'brand': 'acer', 'id': 7},
#>>>   {'brand': 'acer', 'id': 8},
#>>>   {'brand': 'acer', 'id': 9},
#>>>   {'brand': 'acer', 'id': 10}]]
```

Now we want to interleave the results. The basic idea is that we want to take from largest pool more often because it's going to take the longest to exhaust. So each iteration we want to take the longest and `pop` one of its items., only we don't want to repeat. We can do this by taking two different groups, the two largest, and interleaving their results.

We stop when none of the groups have any items left.

```
from heapq import nlargest

shufflatored = []
while any(items_by_brand):
    items1, items2 = nlargest(2, items_by_brand, key=len)

    if items1: shufflatored.append(items1.pop())
    if items2: shufflatored.append(items2.pop())
```

The `heapq` module is a little known but *bloody brilliant* module. In fact with a fair bit of effort this could be made more efficient by keeping `items_by_brand` as a heap. However it's not really worth the effort because the other tools for working with heaps don't take `key`s, which requires obscure workarounds.

So that's it. If you want to allow doubling-up, you can replace

```
    if items1: shufflatored.append(items1.pop())
    if items2: shufflatored.append(items2.pop())
```

with

```
    if items1: shufflatored.append(items1.pop())
    if items1: shufflatored.append(items1.pop())
    if items2: shufflatored.append(items2.pop())
    if items2: shufflatored.append(items2.pop())
```

!

## EDIT

You want something deterministic? *Well why didn't you say so?*

```
lst = list(range(20))

lst[::2], lst[1::2] = lst[1::2], lst[::2]

lst
#>>> [1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8, 11, 10, 13, 12, 15, 14, 17, 16, 19, 18]
```

Magic, isn't it?

Hopefully you know about this method to swap values in-place:

```
a = 1
b = 2

a, b = b, a

a
#>>> 2

b
#>>> 1
```

Well, `lst[::2]` is every other value

```
lst[::2]
#>>> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

and `lst[1::2]` is all of the other other values,

```
lst[1::2]
#>>> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

so `lst[::2], lst[1::2] = lst[1::2], lst[::2]` swaps every other value with every other other value!

---

```
import random

items = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4]

[
    iv[1] for iv in
    sorted(
        enumerate(items),
        key=lambda iv: iv[0]+random.choice([-1, 1])
    )
]

#>>> [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]

[
    iv[1] for iv in
    sorted(
        enumerate(range(20)),
        key=lambda iv: iv[0]+random.choice([-1, 1])
    )
]
#>>> [0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 11, 10, 12, 14, 13, 15, 17, 16, 18, 19]
```

This is a *random* shuffle, so the first list doesn't show up most of the shuffles. The result chosen is picked by hand of all the possibilities.

Basically, this algorithm takes a list and indexes it:

```
  items a b c d e f g h i j
indexes 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

It then sorts by the index + a random choice from `[-1, 1]`:

```
  items a b c d e f g h i j
indexes 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
sort by 1 0 3 2 5 4 5 6 9 8
```

And results in

```
  items b a d c f e g h j i
indexes 1 0 3 2 5 4 6 7 9 8
sort by 0 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 8 9
```

And it's shuffled. To change the type of shuffle, say to make it shuffle more or less, change the specifics of the list `[-1, 1]`. You can also try `[-1, 0, 1]`, `[0, 1]` and other variations.

---

The algorithm in steps:

```
indexed = enumerate(items)

shuffled = sorted(indexed, key=lambda iv: iv[0]+random.choice([-1, 1]))

# Remove the index, extract the values out again
result = [iv[1] for iv in shuffled]
```

---

Now, *efficiency*.

If you're quite astute you might realise that sorting is traditionally `O(n log n)`. Python uses TimSort, a wonderful sorting algorithm. Although any comparison sort (aka. sort that compares values) has to have an *upper bound* of at least `O(n log n)`, they can also have a *lower bound* as low as `O(n)`!

This is because sorting an already-sorted list is trivial as long as you check whether it's sorted. TimSort has a localised idea of "sorted" and it will detect very quickly when the values are sorted. This means that because they're only somewhat-shuffled TimSort would perform something closer to `O(kn)` where `k` is the "shuffled-ness" of the list, which is much less than `log n`!

Comment: it is a good way to sort, but in reality, I want to go with some fix rules instead of random. Think about I have a list of products with brand names, I don't want the same brand product next to each other, but with an even distance, I am thinking in a loop save previous 2 items in a separate list and check against to next items,  and if it's same to previous item, keep looping to next different item, but it might not the best approach to go with.

Comment: Nice super-swap, but unless I'm mistaken this mixes only groups of four elements, so (a) the initial list has to be sorted (not a problem, but should be noted in the answer) and (b) it won't work if there are many equal elements adjacent to each other (i.e., in the same group of four). In particular, it does not work too well for the example provided in the question.

Comment: I've possibly misunderstood the question, but note that his example ends with `[...,e,e,e,e,e]`.

Comment: I am still trying different model actually, your are right that the problem I am trying to solve is more complex than items from the example. In fact, There will be more than 10k products across 1000 brands in a list, and what I want to sort is make sure same brand's product are not at adjacent place, but with a deterministic order, so I don't want the order change every time user visit. I guess this is an sorting algorithm that someone else might be interested, it's always helpful to get different ideas like from Veedrac and try different things.

Comment: The [...,e,e,e,e,e] part is because no more items to be inserted to make the distance. for example, 100 products from IBM, 5 products from Acer, 6 products from Apple, etc, IBM's brand products might be in adjacent places if no more other brands to mix it up.

Comment: Why aren't you allowed `[a,a,b,b,c,c,e,e,b,b,e,e,c,c,e,e,a,b,c]` then?

Comment: Hi Veedrac, it is possible, the example I give might be more very clear. I will edit my question