# c++ - Arranging vector elements in a specific order

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I'm beginning programming, so sorry for my lack of knowledge.
How can I set elements in vector  in a specific order? I would like to swap elements in the way that there won't be same elements next to each other.
For example vector contains:

```
{1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4}
```

and I'd like it to be like:

```
{1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4}
```

Thanks for help.

edit:
Hello again, I found not the best solution, maybe you can take a look and correct it?

```
   map<unsigned,unsigned> Map;
   for(vector<unsigned>::iterator i=V.begin();i!=V.end();++i)
     {
      map<unsigned,unsigned>::iterator f=Map.find(*i);
      if(f==Map.end()) Map[*i]=1;
      else ++f->second;
     }
   for(bool more=true;more;)
     {
      more=false;
      for(map<unsigned,unsigned>::iterator i=Map.begin();i!=Map.end();++i)
        {
         if(i->second)
           {
            --i->second;
            cout<<i->first<<", ";
            more=true;
           }
        }            
     }
```

Now, for  { 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 } it gives me { 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4 } instead of e.g { 4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2 }. How can it be done? Thanks

credits: _13th_Dragon

Comment: What if this is impossible? Depending on what you want, though `std::unique` could possibly help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to separate items of the same type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375831/algorithm-to-separate-items-of-the-same-type)

Comment: You have to develop an algorithm how to do that. Then you should be concerned with implementing it. At first sight it seems as not such a simple problem.

Comment: @chris, thanks, but I dont see the way how it could help me.. If this "sort" is impossible it could return 0 or any other info, the vector wouldn't be used anymore. Maybe you know an algorithm which randomize elements including my condition? :)

Comment: there are many solutions. any other requirements?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, thanks, that's all my requirements. Just swap them in the way that the same elements won't be next to each other, if it cant'be done just return 0. Could you propose some of your solutions?

Comment: @DonReba I disagree that that is a duplicate - this just aims to not have 2 consecutive items of the same type, where-as that aims to maximize the distance of elements of the same type (although some answers to that probably apply to this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Count the occurrences of each value.
2. Starting with the most-frequent value, alternate it with less-frequent values.

In order to achieve (1), one can simply use `std::map<V, unsigned>`. However, for the second, one needs an ordered set of `std::pair<V, unsigned int>`, ordered by the second value. Since we want to keep track of how many times we need to use a given value, the second value cannot be constant. Also, we don't want to change the order if we happen to decrease the count of a given value much. All in all we get

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

// In the pair, first is the original value, while 
// second is the number occurrences of that value.
typedef std::pair<int, unsigned> value_counter;

int main(){
  std::vector<int> sequence = { 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2 , 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 };
  std::map<int, unsigned> count;

  for( auto i : sequence){
    count[i]++;
  }

  std::vector<value_counter> store( count.size() );
  std::copy(count.begin(), count.end(), store.begin());

  // Sort by the second value
  std::sort(store.begin(), store.end(), 
    [](const value_counter& a, const value_counter& b){
      return a.second > b.second;
  });

  std::vector<int> result;

  // We need two indices, one for the current value
  // and the other one for the alternative
  for(unsigned i = 0, j = 1; i < store.size(); ++i){
    while(store[i].second > 0){
      result.push_back(store[i].first);
      store[i].second--;
      if(store[i].second == 0)
        continue;

      if( j <= i)
        j = i + 1;
      while(j < store.size() && store[j].second == 0)
        ++j;
      if(j >= store.size()){
        std::cerr << "Not enough elements for filling!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
      }
      else {
        result.push_back(store[j].first);
        store[j].second--;
      }
    }
  }

  for( auto r : result){
    std::cout << r << " ";
  }
}
```

Instead of using a `typedef` you could create an alternative counter which has better names than `first` and `second`, but that makes copying from the map a little bit more verbose.

Comment: Thank you! For now it's the best solution I have found. Thank you again :)

Comment: @pablo7890: If you're interested in the algorithm's complexity: it should be O(n log k), where k is the number of distinct values.

Comment: thanks. It could be useful for me. I have one more question, previosuly I didn't think that I have to specify the first and last element. Could it be implemented in your algorithm? I probably know how to add first element: after defining vector <int> result just push_back (first_element) and start the loop from 1 not from 0, but I have completely no idea, how make it working for adding last element, so the last one and previous one wouldn't be the same..

Comment: Wait, the last must not match the first? That should not happen. The only way this can happen, is that one value has n occurences and the whole thing is 2n - 1 long. If this happens you can't do anything against it. Otherwise, the algorithm should prevent this.

Comment: Well, maybe I should show an example, what I'm trying to do, because I don't know if I understood you correctly (english isn't my premier lang). Vector is  { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 } and First = 3; Last = 1; so output could be { 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1 }. Do you know any way how to do that? I'm looking for solution in the web and I'm afraid there's no simple algorithm. Thanks!