# "Properly" organise (spread out) x and y data

Tags: python, variables, fractions

Not really sure how to word this question, so I will give an example of what I want.

I have two variables xsteps and ysteps.

If xsteps is 4 and ysteps is 2, then I would like a variable result to be "x, x, y, x, x, y"

If xsteps is 10 and ysteps is 5, then I would like result to be
"x, x, y, x, x, y, x, x, y, x, x, y, x, x, y"

If xsteps is 15 and ysteps is 5 then I would like result to be "x, x, x, y, x, x, x, y, x, x, x, y, x, x, x, y, x, x, x, y"

If xsteps is 1 and ysteps is 6, I would like result to be "x, y, y, y, y, y, y"

If xsteps is 4 and ysteps is 4, I would like result to be "x, y, x, y, x, y, x, y"

If xsteps is 10 and ysteps is 4, I would like result to be "x, x, y, x, x, y, x, x, y, x, x, y, x, x"

Xsteps and ysteps are not always easily divisible. If they do not divide, then I would just like them to be kind of separated out. It does not need to be perfect, just so it spreads them out reasonable well.

Really, I need the xsteps and ysteps variables organised into one variable that spreads them out.

Comment: Is one always a proper divisor of the other?

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Write the algorithm down and show us what you've tried. You've tagged the question with "Python" yet you didn't show us a piece of code.

Comment: @tobias_k no, not necessarily

Comment: Then show an example for when it's not the case.

Comment: @freakish thats because I am not sure where to start and am hoping that someone can help me. It is tagged "python" because I would like it to be written in python

Comment: This is probably overkill for this problem, but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375831/algorithm-to-separate-items-of-the-same-type/12376710#12376710) is a related question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
from __future__ import division
def spreadout(X, Y):
    ratio = len(X) / len(Y)
    result = []
    while X or Y:
        if not Y or len(X)/len(Y) >= ratio:
            result.append(X.pop())
        else:
            result.append(Y.pop())
    return result
```

The idea behind the algorithm is to determine the ratio of the `X` and`Y` lists and to alternately `pop` elements from either of the lists to keep the ratio in the `result` list similar.

This implementaiton works with lists of arbitrary elements and will return the result as a list. If you want just your `x,y` string, the code can be simplified and optimized some, e.g. using `len` this often would be wasteful is you have very long lists of `x`s and `y`s. Or you can just write a wrapper for that:

```
def xy_wrapper(x, y):
    return ",".join(spreadout(['x'] * x, ['y'] * y))
```

Example Output:

```
>>> spreadout(range(6), list("ABC"))
[5, 'C', 4, 3, 'B', 2, 1, 'A', 0]
>>> xy_wrapper(5, 17)
'x,y,y,y,y,x,y,y,y,x,y,y,y,y,x,y,y,y,x,y,y,y'
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution - similar to mine but I think mine should have a better performance since I'm not creating intermediate lists - please take a look and judge me :)

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo My solution is certainly not the fastest, but then again, its a bit more versatile. In fact, your solution looks 99% like what I had at first (did not post it then) before deciding to make it more generic. Neat trick for avoiding zero-division, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
def spread_generator(xsteps, ysteps):
    ratio = xsteps / ysteps
    while xsteps > 0 or ysteps > 0:
        if xsteps > ratio * ysteps:
            yield "x"
            xsteps -= 1
        else:
            yield "y"
            ysteps -= 1

xsteps = 7
ysteps = 3
result = [x for x in spread_generator(xsteps, ysteps)]
# Next line will make result variable hold desired value
result.reverse()
print result
# ['x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'x'] 
# And if you want string
result_as_str = ",".join(result)
print result_as_str
# x,x,y,x,x,y,x,x,y,x
```

The crucial value is the `ratio` between `x` and `y` steps.
The list is reversed in the beginning, so we reverse it.
Remember that `list.reverse()` modifies the list in place and returns `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone beat me to the punch with a much nicer response, but I've written it now!

This would do close to what you want, but your example for (10, 4) doesn't work the way you have specified it.

```
def xy_spread(xsteps, ysteps):
    out = []

    if xsteps == 0:
        out = ['y'] * ysteps    
    else:
        y_per_x = float(ysteps) / float(xsteps)
        y_budget = 0.0

        for _ in xrange(xsteps):
            out.append('x')
            y_budget += y_per_x

            while y_budget >= 1:
                y_budget -= 1
                out.append('y')

    return ','.join(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily pretty, but functional. 
Basically it seems you want to split the xsteps into chunks, and intersperse a "y" between the chunks until either the x's or y's run out.

```
def get_chunks(mylist, n):
    """
    Adapted from:
    http://www.how2code.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-split-a-list-into-chunks-in-python/
    """
    if n == 0:
        return mylist
    else:
        return [mylist[x:x+n] for x in range(0, len(mylist), n)]

def combine(xs=0, ys=0):
    """
    >>> combine(xs=4, ys=2)
    x,x,y,x,x,y
    >>> combine(xs=10, ys=5)
    x,x,y,x,x,y,x,x,y,x,x,y,x,x,y
    >>> combine(xs=15, ys=5)
    x,x,x,y,x,x,x,y,x,x,x,y,x,x,x,y,x,x,x,y
    >>> combine(xs=1, ys=6)
    x,y,y,y,y,y,y
    >>> combine(xs=4, ys=4)
    x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y
    >>> combine(xs=10, ys=4)
    x,x,y,x,x,y,x,x,y,x,x,y,x,x
    """
    output = list()
    x = ['x'] * xs
    y = ['y'] * ys
    step = xs // ys
    xchunks = get_chunks(x, step)

    while xchunks or y:
        if xchunks:
            output += xchunks.pop()
        if y:
            output += y.pop()

    print ','.join(output)
```