# sort list so that the gap between equal elements is as large as possible

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting

Lets assume I've got an unsorted [`List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) containing `a, a, b, b, a, c` and I want this sequence sorted so that the gaps between equal elements are as large as possible. So in case of this sample sequence a possible output could be `b, a, c, a, b, a`. In my application it wouldn't be that important that the gaps are at its exact average maximum, but there shouldn't be two equal elements next to each other whenever possible. So my indention is to maximize the smallest gaps.

Comment: What does "a gap that is large as possible" means? How do you quantify the gaps? Sum the distances between all equal elements? By this definition, it is possible for the maximal solution to contain adjacent equal elements. So you need to better define the problem.

Comment: Do you know the range of the items in the list?

Comment: Well, it would a better definition, that the smallest gap should be at the maximum. In my case the elements are different servers. I'm going to make a request/connection to them (which may be expensiv on server side). To reduce load to the servers I add a small delay between them. To better distribute the load on the servers over time I'd like to sort the connections before.

Comment: I slightly edited my question, so the problem is (hopefully) better defined now.

Comment: @miho > with your remark, I'm thinking a real load balancer would be better. Or maybe just rely on randomness when calling the servers, which should lead to an equal repartition of calls.

Comment: How many items will you have to handle (approximately)?

Comment: Right, but a load balancer would make things more complicated and this is only required once after the restart (which should happen quite rarely). So I would like to keep the effort low. List contains around 200 elements and contains a lot of duplicates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to separate items of the same type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375831/algorithm-to-separate-items-of-the-same-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start from measuring frequency per each unique element:

```
scala> val l = List("a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "c")
l: List[String] = List(a, a, b, b, a, c)

scala> val in = l.toSet[String].map(x => x -> l.count(x==)).toList.sortBy(_._2).reverse
in: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,3), (b,2), (c,1))
```

So now you can generate more-less scattered list:

```
def shuffle[T](l: List[T]) = {

   def fill(n: Int, l: List[List[T]], s: T) = 
      l.take(n + 1).reduce(_ ++ List(s) ++ _) ++ l.drop(n + 1).flatten

   val in = l.toSet[T].map(x => x -> l.count(x==)).toList.sortBy(_._2).reverse

   val initial = in.head._2 -> List.fill(in.head._2)(in.head._1)

   in.tail.foldLeft(initial){case ((size, acc), (value, count)) => 
     count -> fill(count, acc.grouped(acc.size / size).toList, value)
   }._2
}

scala> shuffle(l)
res32: List[String] = List(a, b, c, a, b, a)
```

Every next iteration here is based on previous one with higher frequency: elements just inserted into list (from previous iteration) as broad as possible. So it may not be so effective if frequency is dropping down significantly between iterations as high frequent elements may not be "scrumbled" enough.

This algorithm isn't trying to maximise every distance - it's trying to reduce probabilty of grouped elements appearance to the minimum. Just random shuffling should do the simillar thing if you're fine with less precise result as it produces groups with still small but a bit higher probability here:

```
scala> scala.util.Random.shuffle(l)
res34: List[String] = List(a, b, c, b, a, a)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the commenter said, there is no unique solution because it depends on your cost function. My idea would be along the following line, looking only for right neighbours and assigning them a score of `list.size` if there is no other equal element:

```
def maxGaps[A](in: List[A]): List[A] = {
  if (in.isEmpty) return in

  def noPairs(xs: List[A]): Boolean =
    xs.sliding(2, 1).forall { case List(a, b) => a != b }

  val (good, bad) = in.permutations.partition(noPairs)
  val candidates = if (good.nonEmpty) good else bad

  val maxDist = in.size

  def calcScore(xs: List[A], accum: Int = 0): Int =
    xs match {
      case head :: tail =>
        val i = tail.indexOf(head)
        val j = if (i < 0) maxDist else i
        calcScore(tail, accum + j)      
      case Nil => accum
    }

  candidates.maxBy(calcScore(_))
}

maxGaps("aabbac".toList) // abacab
```