# Sorting a list depending on multiple elements within the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

is it possible to implement a python key for sorting depending on multiple list elements?

For example:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And I want to sort the list depending on the difference between two elements, so that the delta is maximized between them.

Expected result:

```
list = [1, 4, 2, 3] # delta = 4-1 + 4-2 + 3-2 = 6
```

Other result would also be possible, but 1 is before 4 in the origin array so 1 should be taken first:

```
list = [4, 1, 3, 2] # delta = 4-1 + 3-1 + 3-2 = 6
```

I want to use python `sorted` like:

```
sorted(list, key=lambda e1, e2: abs(e1-e2))
```

Is there any possibility to do it this way? Maybe there is another library which could be used.

Comment: Suggest you read the [**Sorting HOW TO**](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

Comment: First off, never use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in

Comment: Related: [Algorithm to separate items of the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12375831/1639625)

Comment: @ᴬᴶᵁᴾᴾᴬᴸ jep you are right, thanks for the advice. - here it was just for an example purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since (as you showed  us) there could be multiple different results - it means that this sorting/order is not deterministic and hence you can't apply a key function to it.

That said, it's easy to implement the sorting by yourself:

```
def my_sort(col):
    res = []
    while col:
        _max = max(col)
        col.remove(_max)
        res.append(_max)

        if col:
            _min = min(col)
            col.remove(_min)
            res.append(_min)

    return res


print(my_sort([1,2,3,4]))  # [4, 1, 3, 2]
```

This solution runs in `O(n^2)` but it can be improved by sorting `col` in the beginning and then instead of looking for `max` and `min` we can extract the items in the beginning and the end of the list. By doing that we'll reduce the time complexity to `O(n log(n))`

**EDIT**

Per your comment below: if the index plays a role, again, it's not a "real" sorting :) that said, this solution can be engineered to keep the smaller index first and etc:

```
def my_sort(col):
    res = []
    while col:
        _max = max(col)
        max_index = col.index(_max)
        col.remove(_max)

        if col:
            _min = min(col)
            min_index = col.index(_min)
            col.remove(_min)
            if max_index < min_index:
                res.extend([_max, _min])
            else:
                res.extend([_min, _max])
            continue
        res.append((_max))

    return res

print(my_sort([1,2,3,4])) # [1, 4, 2, 3]
```

Comment: the problem with this function is, that it does not take the index into account. so the exact output should be `[1, 4, 2, 3]` because `1` was before `4` in the origin list.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is quite brute force; however, it is still a possibility:

```
from itertools import permutations
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
final_list = ((i, sum(abs(i[b]-i[b+1]) for b in range(len(i)-1))) for i in permutations(list, len(list)))
final_lists = max(final_list, key=lambda x:x[-1])
```

Output:

```
((2, 4, 1, 3), 7)
```

Note that the output is in the form: `(list, total_sum))`

Comment: I'd suggest making `final_list` a generator: `final_list = (...)` this way it at least does not have O(n!) _memory_ consumption. (Also, I'd put the calculation of the key into the `key` function itself.)

Comment: okay, as far as I understand it is not possible by using a simple key function. Maybe I thought using the `functools.cmp_to_key` have you ever tried this?

Comment: This solution is valid but the "brute force" part makes it run in a time complexity of `O(n!)`...