# Distribute list of dictionaries by key evenly

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{'User ID': '111',
  'Full Name': 'name a',
  'Role: Name': 'role a'},
 {'User ID': '222',
  'Full Name': 'name b',
  'Role: Name': 'role a'},
 {'User ID': '232',
  'Full Name': 'name c',
  'Role: Name': 'role b'},
 {'User ID': '223',
  'Full Name': 'name d',
  'Role: Name': 'role d'},
 {'User ID': '444',
  'Full Name': 'name e',
  'Role: Name': 'role d'}]
```

I have used the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375831/algorithm-to-separate-items-of-the-same-type/12376710#12376710) to sort the roles evenly in a list. But I also need the their 'Full Name' as well.

So basically I need to sort the dictionary evenly by role, is this possible with the linked answer?

I don't want the dictionary roles ordered like `[a, a, a, b, c, c]`, I want it like `[a,b,a,c,a,c]` or something like this anyway. Similar to how the linked question would do it.

Comment: Can you provide slightly bigger chunk of the data? Containing different roles and repeated as well.

Comment: just added some more, basically there are about 180 names with varying number of roles, but will be about 20 different roles, i need these roles sorted as evenly as possible

Comment: the question i linked does a really good job of sorting a list of roles that i give it, i just can't work out how to also get the name, because right now it's just a list of roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code as below:

```
import pprint
import random
from functools import partial
from operator import itemgetter


data = [{'User ID': '111',
         'Full Name': 'name a',
         'Role: Name': 'role a'},
        {'User ID': '222',
         'Full Name': 'name b',
         'Role: Name': 'role a'},
        {'User ID': '232',
         'Full Name': 'name c',
         'Role: Name': 'role b'},
        {'User ID': '223',
         'Full Name': 'name d',
         'Role: Name': 'role d'},
        {'User ID': '444',
         'Full Name': 'name e',
         'Role: Name': 'role d'}]

def optimize(items, quality_function, stop=1000):
    no_improvement = 0
    best = 0
    while no_improvement < stop:
        i = random.randint(0, len(items) - 1)
        j = random.randint(0, len(items) - 1)
        copy = items[::]
        copy[i], copy[j] = copy[j], copy[i]
        q = quality_function(copy)
        if q > best:
            items, best = copy, q
            no_improvement = 0
        else:
            no_improvement += 1
    return items


def quality_maxmindist(items, key=None):
    if key is None:
        def identity(e): return e

        key = identity

    s = 0
    for k, item in { key(item) : item for item in items}.items():
        indcs = [i for i in range(len(items)) if key(items[i]) == k]
        if len(indcs) > 1:
            s += sum(1. / (indcs[i + 1] - indcs[i]) for i in range(len(indcs) - 1))
    return 1. / s


quality_fun = partial(quality_maxmindist, key=itemgetter("Role: Name"))


res = optimize(data, quality_fun)
pprint.pprint(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'Full Name': 'name a', 'Role: Name': 'role a', 'User ID': '111'},
 {'Full Name': 'name d', 'Role: Name': 'role d', 'User ID': '223'},
 {'Full Name': 'name c', 'Role: Name': 'role b', 'User ID': '232'},
 {'Full Name': 'name b', 'Role: Name': 'role a', 'User ID': '222'},
 {'Full Name': 'name e', 'Role: Name': 'role d', 'User ID': '444'}]
```

Basically, you add a `key` parameter to the function `quality_maxmindist` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375831/algorithm-to-separate-items-of-the-same-type/12376710#12376710)), this key parameter is going to be use to determine how to items are equal.

In the particular case of your question, you could use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) on `"Role: Name"`, this way items with the same role will be considered equal. See below the code changes with comments:

```
def quality_maxmindist(items, key=None):
    if key is None:
        def identity(e): return e

        key = identity

    s = 0
    # notice that you need to use a dictionary for finding unique items by key
    for k, item in { key(item) : item for item in items}.items():
        indcs = [i for i in range(len(items)) if key(items[i]) == k]  # notice
        if len(indcs) > 1:
            s += sum(1. / (indcs[i + 1] - indcs[i]) for i in range(len(indcs) - 1))
    return 1. / s


quality_fun = partial(quality_maxmindist, key=itemgetter("Role: Name"))
res = optimize(data, quality_fun)
```